# Can An SQLite database be locked ? as in one cannot be opened externally and add rows to a table?

Tags: database, sqlite, locking

ok lets assume i have a table  now it has only two rows in it and i dont want anyone to add any more rows to it? it can be accessed by c sharp but it should not be openable using SQLite admin or any other db manager , is that possible??

I dont want the user to add another row outside c sharp can this be done????

triggers???

Answer (score 1):

What connector are you using from C#?

If you are using System.Data.SQLite from [phxsoftware](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) it supports encryption. You could use that to prevent access to the database.

**EDIT:**
As far a i understand it you will only be able to access it through the System.Data.SQLite connector then.

Comment: yea i am using System.Data.SQLite , and i am using encryption . its just that im worried abt the user modifying the encrypted data outside C# and tht way no one can login :( so i thought abt hardcoring the username and paswrd into the application , what do u think??